# eclipse NullPointerRxception

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

Can anyone pls help me: i don't find what I've done wrong in my activity.

This is the error from the logcat:

```
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862): Process: pack.coderzheaven, PID: 26862
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{pack.coderzheaven/pack.coderzheaven.Bestellung}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1965)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at pack.coderzheaven.Bestellung.<init>(Bestellung.java:16)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2222)
11-27 10:37:25.551: E/AndroidRuntime(26862):    ... 11 more
```

and the java-file:

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;
import android.widget.NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Bestellung extends Activity implements NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener {


DecimalFormat f = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

final TextView bierpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bierpreis);
final TextView seidlpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlpreis);
final TextView weinpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinpreis);
final TextView spritzerpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzerpreis);
final TextView weinmixpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixpreis);
final TextView colapreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colapreis);
final TextView limoklpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklpreis);
final TextView limoklgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgespreis);
final TextView limogrgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgespreis);


final TextView biererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biererg);
final TextView seidlerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlerg);
final TextView weinerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinerg);
final TextView spritzererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzererg);
final TextView weinmixerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixerg);
final TextView colaerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colaerg);
final TextView limoklerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklerg);
final TextView limoklgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgeserg);
final TextView limogrgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgeserg);
final TextView enderg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enderg);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bestellung);


    NumberPicker bn=
        (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.biernummer);
        bn.setMaxValue(100);
        bn.setMinValue(0);
        bn.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker Picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                float bp = Float.valueOf(bierpreis.getText().toString());
                Double zz = (double) (newVal*bp);
                biererg.setText(f.format(zz).toString());
                enderg();
            }
        });


        ..........


    NumberPicker lggn=
        (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.limogrgesnummer);
        lggn.setMaxValue(100);
        lggn.setMinValue(0);
        lggn.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker Picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                float lggp = Float.valueOf(limogrgespreis.getText().toString());
                Double zz = (double) (newVal*lggp);
                limogrgeserg.setText(f.format(zz).toString());
                enderg();
            }
        });
}

@Override
public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private void enderg() {

    float a = Float.valueOf(biererg.getText().toString());
    float b = Float.valueOf(seidlerg.getText().toString());
    float c = Float.valueOf(weinerg.getText().toString());
    float d = Float.valueOf(spritzererg.getText().toString());
    float e = Float.valueOf(weinmixerg.getText().toString());
    float g = Float.valueOf(colaerg.getText().toString());
    float h = Float.valueOf(limoklerg.getText().toString());
    float i = Float.valueOf(limoklgeserg.getText().toString());
    float j = Float.valueOf(limogrgeserg.getText().toString());
    Double z = (double) (a+b+c+d+e+g+h+i+j);
    enderg.setText(f.format(z).toString());     
}
}
```

the logcat says that there is an error in line 16 (as I hope I understood it right) (final textview Bierpreis....) but i can't find any error.

So I hope you can help me! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`findViewById` can be used after `onAttach` is called, not before, because the context object you are indirecting using has not been yet initialized. Move all the initialization in `onCreate` after `setContentView`

first use `setContentView(R.layout.bestellung);`

then use

```
final TextView bierpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bierpreis);
final TextView seidlpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlpreis);
final TextView weinpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinpreis);
final TextView spritzerpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzerpreis);
final TextView weinmixpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixpreis);
final TextView colapreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colapreis);
final TextView limoklpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklpreis);
final TextView limoklgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgespreis);
final TextView limogrgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgespreis);


final TextView biererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biererg);
final TextView seidlerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlerg);
final TextView weinerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinerg);
final TextView spritzererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzererg);
final TextView weinmixerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixerg);
final TextView colaerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colaerg);
final TextView limoklerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklerg);
final TextView limoklgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgeserg);
final TextView limogrgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgeserg);
final TextView enderg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enderg);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your references from xml in `onCreate` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bestellung);
final TextView bierpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bierpreis);
final TextView seidlpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlpreis);
final TextView weinpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinpreis);
final TextView spritzerpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzerpreis);
final TextView weinmixpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixpreis);
final TextView colapreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colapreis);
final TextView limoklpreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklpreis);
final TextView limoklgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgespreis);
final TextView limogrgespreis = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgespreis);


final TextView biererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.biererg);
final TextView seidlerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seidlerg);
final TextView weinerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinerg);
final TextView spritzererg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.spritzererg);
final TextView weinmixerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weinmixerg);
final TextView colaerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.colaerg);
final TextView limoklerg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklerg);
final TextView limoklgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limoklgeserg);
final TextView limogrgeserg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.limogrgeserg);
final TextView enderg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.enderg);

...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading your code I can only guess where your error occurs but it seems that you're getting a **NullPointerException** in these lines:

```
GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

Your XML-layout-file doesn't contain a GridView with the ID gridview so `findViewById(R.id.gridview)` returns **null**. Right after that you try to call `setAdapter(...)` which itself will most likely call the Exception.

It would be very helpful if you provide us with more information about the Exception.